# How to increase Chart.js yAxes' height to prevent overlapping

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

[overlapping problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETO0x.png)
How to config the chart.js (using react-chartjs-2) to prevent the overlapping problem.
I have changed the barThickness and caused the overlapping.
Which property can be used to change the group/category(?) height to prevent this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `barPercentage`  Configuration?

```
  options: {
     indexAxis: 'y',
        barPercentage :0.5
    }
 }
```